# How to write the type declaration of an Haskell function with no arguments?

Tags: haskell

How to write the type declaration of an haskell function without arguments?

Comment: I think you'll need to be clearer about what you mean by a "function without arguments". Do you mean something like a value like `5` of type `Int`, or something that really has a function type but is defined without any explicit arguments, like `f = const 3` ?

Comment: `f = const 3` has a type signature `f :: b -> Integer`. It has thus an argument, it just ignores it

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no such thing as a function without arguments, that would be just a value. Sure, you can write such a declaration:

```
five :: Int
five = 5
```

It might look more like what you asked for if I make it

```
five' :: () -> Int
five' () = 5
```

but that's completely equivalent (unless you write something ridiculous like `five' undefined`) and superfluent<sup>1</sup>.

If what you mean is something like, in C

```
void scream() {
  printf("Aaaah!\n");
}
```

then that's again not a function but an action. (C programmers do call it function, but you might better say *procedure*, everybody would understand.) What I said above holds pretty much the same way, you'd use

```
scream :: IO()
scream = putStrLn "Aaaah!"
```

Note that the empty `()` do in this case not have anything to do with not having arguments (that follows already from the absence of `->` arrows), instead it means there is also no *return value*, it's just a "side-effect-only" action.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, it differs in one relevant way: `five` is a [*constant applicative form*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constant_applicative_form), which sort of means it's memoised. If I had defined such a constant in some roundabout way (e.g. `sum $ 5 : replicate 1000000 0`) then the lengthy calculation would be carried out only once, even if `five` is evaluated multiple times during a program run. OTOH, wherever you would have written out `five' ()`, the calculation would have been done anew.

Comment: you can call it *action* or *procedure*, but syntactically it is just a function like all the others, and yes, in my case i actually wanted to group some side effects together, and i wanted to know how to declare the expected returned type. thanks

Comment: It is syntactically a function in almost every programming language, but not in Haskell. Here, _function_ has a very specific meaning – basically, a lambda abstraction. If something doesn't permit you to apply it to some argument, then it's not a function. Read [this blog post by Conal](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell).

Comment: So what should you use instead? How can you put a value in scope for every function?

Comment: @Max: any value that's declared on the top-level will be in scope for every function, no need to do anything. (And, of course, also for things that aren't functions...)

Comment: @leftaroundabout You said _There is no such thing as a function without arguments_. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm7aEU-8enI) video at 24:00 the instructor rewrites the function *quadruple* to make it more concise and he just defines it without any arguments and claims that there is no need to pass an argument to it because it is just a function composition. How is it possible? - For a function composition we do need an argument as he writes in his example (f . g) x = f ( g (x) ). Can you explain it please. I'm totally confused!

Comment: @Infinity: without having watched the referenced video, I assume they're talking about a [point-free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Point-free) definition. You can define a function without _explicitly_ mentioning any parameters, by using composition operators instead. But a function defined this way sure has parameters too, only, they're implicit in the definition. If you will, `f = (+1)` is just syntactic sugar for `f x = x+1`: both define a function with one argument, but the former style avoids actually giving it a name.

Answer (score 14):

Since functions in Haskell are pure (their result only depends on their arguments), the equivalent of a function with no arguments is just a value. For example, `one = 1`.